# hello_world_gles use PPAPI platform can not load plugin

Tags: google-nativeclient, ppapi

env: Chrome v39, sdk pepper_38, vs_addin v1578
use default debug params (`--register-pepper-plugins="$(TargetPath)";application/x-ppapi http://localhost:$(NaClWebServerPort)/$(NaCLIndexHTML) --user-data-dir="$(ProjectDir)/chrome_data" --no-first-run --ppapi-in-process --wait-for-debugger-children`)
load page `index_win.html`, no explicit error.
Here is the result:
[image]
When I change to NaCl64, it runs properly，but can not load the nacl-gdb debugger.
Anyone knows something about this?